# Is there a way to customize the color_continuous_scale argument with hex color code in Plotly Express?

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, geocoding, plotly-express

I've searched around for a while now and I am trying to customize the color scale by hex color code, but I could not find a valid way to do it. Is the default preset color sales the only option for us? This is for a map generated by plotly's mapbox API.

I have gone through their documentation here:
https://plotly.com/python/styling-plotly-express/

Any comment or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out finally so I'll answer myself, setting a custom color scale like below then assigning it to the argument would work:

```
colorscale = [
[0, 'rgb(38, 53, 113)'], 
[0.5, 'rgb(57, 162, 225)'],
[1, 'rgb(234, 32, 41)']
]
```

...and then in the argument:color_continuous_scale = colorscale